# Set input invalid inside custom form control in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have created a custom autocomplete form control, that implements `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator` and integrated it successfully into a reactive form. The input element inside the custom form control uses `ngModel`.

The value of the form component is valid, if the object returned by it contains a numeric ID.

For example `{ id: 1, name: 'Test' }` would be a valid object.

Everything is working fine, but unfortunately the input element has the `ng-valid` CSS class applied to it, since it is not part of the reactive validation process (it uses ngModel).

The input element has my own `appInput directive` applied to it, so I have access to all form related classes like `NgControl`, or `FormGroupDirective`.

This is my custom autocomplete template:

```
<input
    #searchTerm
    appInput
    type="search"
    [ngModel]="name"
    (ngModelChange)="keyupSubject.next($event)"
/>
```

and it is inside a `reactive formGroup`:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
    <div class="col-sm-11">

        <app-autocomplete
            formControlName="name">
        </app-autocomplete>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `ngControl` and `setErrors` inside my appInput directive, but the CSS class is still not set.

```
@Input()
set errors(errors) {
    const control = this._ngControl;
    control.control.setErrors(errors);
}
```

**How do I set the input element inside my custom form control invalid?**
I am asking specifically about the CSS class `ng-invalid` on the input element.

Comment: If you are willing to create your own validation service/component that uses your custom CSS classes, then you should read the following :
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-form-builder-and-validation-management
I had a similar problem bypassed it following the above method. Maybe this is an overkill for one control only but it's a great approach if you have many types of validations.

Comment: I already use a similar approach, but this is not what the question is about.
I need to set ng-invalid on an input element.

Comment: OK sorry, my bad. Please try to pass the formControlName AND the id properties to your custom component like this  : [formControlName]="name" [id]="controlid". **Edit :** id probably not needed... trying to remember how i did it a few months back, sorry...!

Answer (score 1):

In your control get the NgControl

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl = this.inj.get(NgControl);
}
```

Then in your view you can bind any elements to the validity on ngControl:

```
<input [ngClass]="ngControl?.valid ? 'ng-valid' : 'ng-invalid'" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approch, add #searchTerm="ngModel" to the input and test on its validation with : searchTerm.invalid

```
<input
    #searchTerm="ngModel"
    appInput
    type="search"
    [ngModel]="name"
    (ngModelChange)="keyupSubject.next($event)"
/>
<div *ngIf="searchTerm.invalid" class="invalid-field">
   Field Invalid
</div>
```